# Bitcoind clear / reset my testnet to retest some things

Tags: bitcoind, testnet, bitcoin-cli

I'm running bitcoind on centos and want to reset my testnet. I tested one way and now I want to test something else a different way.

For example, I want to clear it so when I do:

```
bitcoin-cli listaccounts
```

No accounts are returned.

AND

```
bitcoin-cli listtransactions
```

No transactions are returned.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Delete the wallet.dat file in your testnet datadir and restart Bitcoin Core. Note that this will destroy all of your coins.

Comment: Didn't work. For some reason I did this and it only deleted some of the wallets. Weird, I'll keep messing with it.

Comment: Are you sure you deleted the right wallet? Any wallet related things are stored in the wallet.dat file and not elsewhere.